# JStree in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jstree

I am super stumped on this one. I have the following code in a directive that creates a jstree. I pull in my data from a http call in a factory. I am able to print out my data in the console right before my tree is created, however my tree never creates. I have tried hardcoding the tree into the data field of the jstree and it displays, but whenever I push my variable to the tree it doesnt work.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,
                        function()
                        {
                            console.log("Tree data:");
                            console.log(scope[attrs.ngModel]);

                            $(element).jstree(    // Setup the tree like you would normally
                        {
                            plugins: ['themes', 'dnd'],
                            core:
                            {
                                themes:
                                {
                                    theme: 'default',
                                    dots: false,
                                    icons: true
                                },
                                check_callback: function(operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more)
                                {
                                    return operation === 'rename_node' ? true : true;
                                },
                                data: scope[attrs.ngModel]
                            }

                        }

                    );


                        }
                    );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
LL